# Easiest ways to prove a list of polynomials is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

What are some of the easiest, most methodical ways to prove the linear independence of $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$ in $\mathcal{P}(\textbf{F})$ for each nonnegative integer $n$.

I saw this method. Is this an appropriate way?

Assume that the list is linearly dependent.

Let $j$ be the largest index in $\{0,...,n\}$ such that $a_j \neq 0$

Then $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n=0\implies$,$x^j=\frac{1}{a_j}(-a_0-\dots-a_{j-1}x^{j-1})$ expressing $x^j$ as a polynomial with degree $j-1$ a contradiction.

Other methods:

Since $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n=0$ holds for all $n$,

this yields the system of equations

$a_0=0$

$a_0+a_1+\dots+ a_n=0$

$a_0+2a_1+\dots+a_n(2)^n=0$

$\dots$

$a_0+a_1(n+1)+\dots+a_n(n+1)^n=0$

The determinant of the coefficient matrix of this system of equations is nonzero implying $a_1=\dots=a_n=0$

Is this method appropriate without using induction?

Also this method:

$a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n=0$

Plugging in $0$ yields $a_0=0$

differentiating both sides,

$2a_2+\dots+na_nx^{n-1}=0$

plugging in $0$ yields $a_n=0$ and so on.

Is this method appropriate without the use of induction?

If these methods need to be proved using induction(the last two) can someone show me how to do this. I am having trouble coming up with a way to prove the last two results by induction. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining $\mathcal P(\mathbb F)$?  In the usual definition, those monomials are independent by definition.

Comment: Your argument is hard to follow.  If you mean "independent as functions on the field $\mathbb F$"  then it simply isn't true.  $x,x^2$ define the same function on the field of two elements, for instance.

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer the question.  How are you defining $\mathcal P_n(\mathbb F)$?  If you write down two expressions like $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i, \sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i$, what does it mean to say that they are "the same"?  Again, the usual definition is "they are the same when $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$".  Which is precisely what linear independence means.

Comment: I know that it's $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,...,n$

Comment: Well, that's linear independence.  If you had a dependence between them you'd have scalars $a_i$ with $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^n0\times x^i$, which would then imply that $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: The usual confusion here arises from the fact that it's different if you define polynomials to be the same if they take the same value when evaluated on the elements of the field.  If your field is large enough (infinite will do) then the two definitions coincide, but not if the fields are finite.

Comment: @lulu will this proof be sufficient suppose $a_{0}+a_{1}x+\dots+a_{n}x^{n}=b_0+b_1x+\dots+b_{n}x^n \implies (a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)x+\dots+(a_n-b_n)x^n=0,a_0=b_0,a_1=b_1,...,a_n=b_n$

Comment: Well, not really. A linear dependence between them would mean that we have $a_i\in \mathbb F$, not all $0$, such that $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i=0$ but $0$ here means the $0-$polynomial, namely $\sum_{i=0}^n0\times x^i$ so we instantly get $a_i=0$ for all $i$, contrary to the assumption of dependence.

Comment: Fix a $n$ and use that the polynomials are a linear vector space. And identify your set of monomials as the canonical base of the polynomials... what happens with the rank of the matrix?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of defining polynomials over $\mathbb F$.

1. You define it as formal combinations $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
   and define de operations in the usual way.
2. A polynomial is a function $f: \mathbb F \to \mathbb F$ given by $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i.$$

The first definition is the one we use when working with general field. These definitions are not equivalent in general. For example, for $\mathbb F = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ we have the non trivial polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x$, but $f(0)=f(1)=0$. So, this $f$ is a non trivial polynomial, but it is the zero function if we think of $f$ as function.

Nevertheless, if $\mathbb F$ is infinite, then the two definitions coincide, as it is the case for $\mathbb F=\mathbb Q,\mathbb R,\mathbb C$, for example. In order to prove that we show the functions $x^i:\mathbb F \to \mathbb F$ are linearly independent. Consider a linear combination of the functions $x^i$: 
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = 0.
$$ 
We have to prove the coefficients $a_i$ are zero. Take $n+1$ pairwise distinct points $x_0, \ldots,x_n$ of $\mathbb F$, which exist because this field is infinite. Then we have the system
\begin{align*}
f(x_0)&=0 \\ 
f(x_1)&=0 \\
\vdots& \\  
f(x_n)&=0
\end{align*}
that can be written in matrix form as:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n\\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n\\
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_0\\
a_1\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}=0.
$$

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n\\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n\\
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n\\
\end{pmatrix}$
is called [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and its determinant is 
$\Pi_{j<i}(x_i-x_j)$, which is non-zero, because the points $x_j$ are all pairwise distinct. Therefore, from the linear system above we conclude the $a_i$ are zero, and , therefore, the funcions $x^i$ are linearly independent.